# Vim: Automated way to reformat and reindent comments?

Tags: vim, formatting

I have some documentation in code that I'd like to format nicely:

```
# book_id - integer
# chapter_id - integer (Optional)
# relative_url - Text: the url of the screencast file on S3, relative to the book's url
# view_count - integer
```

I installed Tabular.vim, which gets me this far:

```
# book_id      - integer
# chapter_id   - integer (Optional)
# relative_url - Text: the url of the screencast file on S3, relative to the book's url
# view_count   - integer
```

I'd like some automated way to generate code like this.  That is, wrapped to 79 chars, indented if continuing a line from a previous comment.  What I get is this:

```
# book_id      - integer
# chapter_id   - integer (Optional)
# relative_url - Text: the url of the screencast file on S3, relative to the
# book's url
# view_count   - integer
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
# book_id      - integer
# chapter_id   - integer (Optional)
# relative_url - Text: the url of the screencast file on S3, relative to the
#                book's url
# view_count   - integer
```

Is it possible to do this with in an existing plugin or hotkey sequence?  I know about `gq`, which will reformat text to a character width set in vim, but it won't add the indentation in things like comments.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `formatlistpat` option(`:set fo+=n` required to work):

#### 1. remove `#`

```
:%s/^# //
```

#### 2. set `flp` option

```
:setl flp=^[^-]*-\\s
```

#### 3. do formatting

<kbd>gggqG</kbd>

#### 4. prepend `#`

```
:%s/^/# /
```

---

You can also use the `indentexpr` option:

#### 2a. set `inde` option

```
:setl inde=15
```

#### 2b. insert empty lines

```
:g/^/pu_
```

#### 5. delete empty comments

```
:g/^# $/d
```

Comment: That's a useful one I both didn't know ***and*** couldn't find: `formatlistpat`. +1

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to indent the new line(s) out to the dash.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to automate arbitrary tasks like these is with the help of recordings. With a recording, you can record any commands you used the **first** time you fix the documentation, and then repeat them very easily.

For example, assuming that your mentioned documentation is at the beginning of the file:

First, use `set textwidth=79` to let Vim know the maximum amount of characters per line. Then:

1. Press `qq` to start recording
2. Press `gg` to go to the beginning of the file
3. Press `gq}` to reformat the documentation block.
4. Press `:Tabularize -` to use your plugin
5. Press `:bnext` to go to the next buffer
6. Press `q` to stop the recording.

Now, if you press `1000@q` the recording would be repeated for all buffers open in vim. You could also just press `@q` whenever you want to perform it for the current file. Take a look at `:help gq` and `:help q` for more information.

Comment: I clarified on my question a bit.  I already use macros, but I want a way to automate everything I've done into one or a few keystrokes, including the indentation out to the - character